# Remove HTML tags from string, but leave the href attributes

Tags: c#, html, .net, regex, string

In case the question's title is not clear.

I would like to parse this:

```
<p><a rel="nofollow" data-xxx="797998" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a> for the win</p>
```

To this:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com StackOverflow for the win
```

I found a lot of useful questions on how to remove HTML tags using an HTML parser or even a regex, but nothing about keeping the HTML attributes.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Don't. Create an HTML element and get the `href` attribute from it.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want with regular expression replacement.

```
string html = "<p><a rel=\"nofollow\" data-xxx=\"797998\" href=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com\">StackOverflow</a> for the win</p>";

string parsed = Regex.Replace(html, "<[^>]+href=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>", "$1 ");
parsed = Regex.Replace(parsed, "<[^>]+>", "");
```

First the href-attributes are extracted and the containing tags are removed. The second run will remove all remaining tags including closing tags and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat specific, but it does what you've asked for.

```
var str = '<p><a rel="nofollow" data-xxx="797998" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a> for the win</p>';

var str = str.replace('</a>', '');
var str = str.replace('</p>', '');
var str = str.replace('">', '');

var p = str.indexOf('href="');

console.log(str.slice(p + 'href="'.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

An example for using strings:

```
private string ParseAttribute(string input, string attributeName)
{
    int startIndex = input.IndexOf(attributeName + "=\"");

    if (startIndex >= 0)
    {
        startIndex += attributeName.Length + 2;
        int endIndex = input.IndexOf('"', startIndex);

        if (endIndex >= 0)
            return input.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
    }

    return string.Empty;
}

// usage
string html = "<p><a rel=\"nofollow\" data-xxx=\"797998\" href=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com\">StackOverflow</a> for the win</p>";

Console.WriteLine(ParseAttribute(html, "href"));
```

This code may have its weaknesses but will do what you requested.

**Edit:** OK I see I missed that you also wanted the elements content. But I leave this code snippet anyway. Maybe it's helpful somehow.

Answer (score -2):

Can be as simple as this:

```
String yourinput = "...";
result = Regex.Replace(yourinput, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP wants to keep the href value. Here's a demo of your answer: https://regexr.com/41n1h